# transpose/swap x,y axes in html table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transform

I have an html table that needs rotating / axis swaping. It can be done off line. Any one know of a tool I can use to do it?

Comment: What's the input sample? Without @colspan and @rowspan the answer is simple, otherwise the algorithm will be complex. Maybe for optimization purpose, one could built a temporaly result with nothing more than calculated cardinality (fine grained traversal passing ocuppated cells), and then output cardinatlty inversion.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution.

Comment: @Dimitre: With the assumption that the table has regular structure.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, I think that this is what @richard wants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="table">
     <xsl:for-each select="tr[1]/td">
      <xsl:variable name="vRowPos" select="position()"/>
      <tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="/table/tr">
        <xsl:variable name="vColPos" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="/table/tr[$vColPos]/td[$vRowPos]"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>A11</td>
  <td>A12</td>
  <td>A13</td>
  <td>A14</td>
  <td>A15</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A21</td>
  <td>A22</td>
  <td>A23</td>
  <td>A24</td>
  <td>A25</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A31</td>
  <td>A32</td>
  <td>A33</td>
  <td>A34</td>
  <td>A35</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**produces the wanted, correct results**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A11</td>
        <td>A21</td>
        <td>A31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A12</td>
        <td>A22</td>
        <td>A32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A13</td>
        <td>A23</td>
        <td>A33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A14</td>
        <td>A24</td>
        <td>A34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A15</td>
        <td>A25</td>
        <td>A35</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Do note**: The assumption is that the table has  *regular* structure.

Comment: The two variables, vNumRows and vNumCols, are defined - but never used.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thank you for noticing this. Must be the result of incomplete edit of a previous version. Will investigate and edit.