# How to add a table control to the form?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to add a table to the form and table contains 2 columns and 3 rows.the 3 rows are Name,Age and Place.In this table at run time i want to update values in the 2nd column for the respected rows.
I want to add table like this

[image]

For eg.In above image Name is the one of the table row item in column1 and in column2 first row contains value of Name.

How can i do it?

Comment: I tried GridView.But in GridView in design part we can only add columns not rows..

Answer (score 1):

Create some kind of container class (that is some kind of collection) that stores your key-value pairs, and bind them to a `DataGrid` at runtime.

---

**Quick'n'dirty example:**

```
Class Container
    Inherits BindingList(Of Value)

    Class Value
        Public Property Key As String
        Public Property Value As Object
    End Class

    Public Sub New()
        Add(New Value With {.Key = "Name"})
        Add(New Value With {.Key = "Age"})
        Add(New Value With {.Key = "Place"})
    End Sub

    Default Public Overloads Property Item(ByVal key As String) As Object
        Get
            Return Me.FirstOrDefault(Function(v) v.Key = key)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            Dim v = Me.FirstOrDefault(Function(e) e.Key = key)
            If v Is Nothing Then
                Add(New Value With {.Key = key, .Value = value})
            Else
                v.Value = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

In your `Form`:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim grd = New DataGrid With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
    Controls.Add(grd)
    Dim container = New Container()

    grd.DataSource = container

    container("Age") = 12
    container("Place") = "Somewhere"
End Sub
```

---

[image]

---

You then have to adjust the apperance of your DataGrid of course, it's up to you.

This way, the grid is bound to the `container` object, and you can read/change values easily.

Comment: This is not supported by the standard `DataGrid`, or any other standard WinForm control. But you could subclass the `DataGrid`, bind this grid in the constructor to a datasource and create a appropriate desginer component that will allow you to add elements to that datasource, but this kinda out of scope of this question/answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try these links These might be helpful

[transpose/swap x,y axes in html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410084/transpose-swap-x-y-axes-in-html-table)

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.2

http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200312/post00920.html

[Convert TD columns into TR rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730699/convert-td-columns-into-tr-rows)